# Using Part of a Class Name as a Variable for .addClass

Tags: jquery, function, class, addclass, var

**BACKGROUND:**
I have nine divs with classes .big1, .big2, .big3, and .small1, .small2, .small3. The divs aren't siblings or parents & children, or I'd be doing this with pure CSS.

I'm adding a class to .big1 when .small1 is hovered over, and .big2 when small2 is hovered over. My current approach **(shown below)** works but is inelegant. Though I'm pretty new to jQuery, I believe it's possible to shrink the code down to a single .addClass function, using variables to change the class names accordingly.

**PROBLEM:** 
I'm trying to set up my code so the number *x* on the end of a hovered .big*x* div is appended to the class name of the .small*x* div that follows, probably by creating a variable out of the numbers on the .big and .small classes. This is where I'm stuck. I've looked at using .split() to grab the number at the end of a .small and .replace() to put that number on the end of the .big, but I can't figure out how to set it up. Suggestions are appreciated!

**jQuery:**

```
$('.small1').hover(
  function(){
    $('.big1').addClass("itemHover");
  },function(){
    $('.big1').removeClass("itemHover");
});

$('.small2').hover(
  function(){
    $('.big2').addClass("itemHover");
  },function(){
    $('.big2').removeClass("itemHover");
});

$('.small3').hover(
  function(){
    $('.big3').addClass("itemHover");
  },function(){
    $('.big3').removeClass("itemHover");
});
```

**Simplified HTML:** (again, the divs in my markup aren't siblings or parents/children)

```
<div class="big1"></div>
<div class="big2"></div>
<div class="big3"></div>
<div class="small1"></div>
<div class="small1"></div>
<div class="small2"></div>
<div class="small2"></div>
<div class="small3"></div>
<div class="small3"></div>
```

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**
This is just to clarify a couple of lines in @Sergio's solution. There were a couple of missing brackets that were breaking the code in FF. The solution below was successfully tested in IE 10, Chrome and FF:

```
$('div[class^="small"]').hover(function () {
    var this_class = $(this).prop('class');
    var filter = $.grep(this_class, function (a) {
        return a ^= 'small';
    });
    $('div.big' + filter).addClass("itemHover");
}, function () {
    $('div[class^="big"]').removeClass("itemHover");
});
```

Comment: Just updated my answer, check the demos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your html looks like but this can be useful:

**Option 1:**
(this works with different classes)

```
$('div[class^="small"').hover(function () {
      var filter = $.grep(this.className.split(' '), function(a) {
           return a.indexOf('small')===0;
      });
    filter = filter[0].split('small')[1];
    $('div.big' + filter).addClass("itemHover");
}, function () {
    $('div[class^="big"').removeClass("itemHover");
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YAMxQ/5/)** (hover with mouse over `S1`)

---

**Option 2:**

```
var all_BIG = $('div[class^="big"');
var all_small = $('div[class^="small"');
all_small.hover(function () {
    var this_ind = $(this).index();
    all_BIG.eq(this_ind).addClass("itemHover");
}, function () {
    all_BIG.removeClass("itemHover");
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5cDyk/1/)** (hover with mouse over `S1`)

Comment: thanks! Works like a charm. I went with Option 1, because I have other classes on the divs as well.

Comment: @Marcatectura, you're welcome. I just updated the answer actually. It had a limitation, it would not work for numbers >9. But now its fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `class name` small for class starting with `small` to get the number with class and use that number with `big`  class.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YAMxQ/4/)**

```
$('[class^=small]').hover(     
  function(){  
      num = this.className.replace('small', '');
    $('.big' + num).addClass("itemHover");

  },function(){
      num = this.className.replace('small', '');
    $('.big' + num).removeClass("itemHover");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - I've tried your solution but for some reason it isn't working; I'm sure I'm just missing something. Do I need to plug in any other information, especially around the '[class^=small]' statement? That's new to me...

Comment: I have written the number extraction statement at wrong place. I have fixed that now.